# How to execute Groovy statements in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to define a variable, but declarative pipelines are more restrictive than scriptive pipelines. How can I do it? It doesn't matter where I put the `String CMD = ...` statement, I get an error, which varies depending on where I put it.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        PATH = "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    }
    stages {
        // The pipeline will fail it can't find terraform
        stage("Check terraform") {
            steps {
                String CMD = (env.DESTROY.toBoolean ? "destroy" : "apply")
                // other steps
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `CMD = (env.DESTROY? "destroy" : "apply")`,  i think `toBoolean` should be a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your code into `script` function
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script
or declare your variable before `pipeline {`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        PATH = "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    }
    stages {
        // The pipeline will fail it can't find terraform
        stage("Check terraform") {
            steps {
               script {        
                  String CMD = (env.DESTROY.toBoolean ? "destroy" : "apply")
               }
                  // other steps
            }
        }
    }
}
```